# Why doesn't Angular 'track by' prevent the '10 $digest() iterations' error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the general idea of "10 $digest() iterations reached" error, but I thought that by using `track by` I could get Angular to realize that the list is not actually changing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TrackBy test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div simple-list items="theItems | filter:'e'"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.theItems = [
          {Id: 1, Name: 'One'},
          {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'},
          {Id: 3, Name: 'Three'},
          {Id: 4, Name: 'Four'}
        ];
      }])
      .directive('simpleList', [function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            items: '='
          },
          replace: true,
          template: "<p ng-repeat='item in items track by item.Id'>{{item.Name}}</p>"
        };
      }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This correctly displays only those names containing "e", but the console shows the 10 digest iterations error.

Why doesn't `track by` help in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isolate scope bindings ('=', '&', and '@') only work on properties of the parent scope.  Your items attribute has an angular expression, not just a simple property.  You'll have to make 'items' either a property  or a function of the parent scope, and do your filtering either in the directive itself or in the controller.

I got it to work by replacing your first items declaration with this:

```
<div simple-list items="theItems"></div>
```

and your directive template with this:

```
template: "<p ng-repeat='item in items | filter:\"e\" track by item.Id'>{{item.Name}}</p>"
```

The track by probably isn't even necessary since your problem was with the isolated scope attribute.

I personally would do this filtering in function in my controller.  The syntax for using a filter in a controller is a little tricky, but it makes it cleaner to tie to a directive with isolate scope.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand how to work around it by putting the filter inside the directive, but I'm looking for a way to send the filtered list in from the controller. Wouldn't you agree it seems like a 'natural' thing that should work?

Comment: It probably doesn't work that way because of the error you just saw.  Since the value of angular expressions can change during every $digest cycle, the directive code would be called repeatedly.  Logically the "isolated" scope shouldn't have its properties changed once it's been isolated unless it explicitly references the parent scope in some later code.